# Qr Code Using primeFaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, qr-code

Using PrimeFaces 5.1 and After adding barcode4j-light-2.1 and qrgen-1.4 jar files
still not able to generate Qr code. code for primeFaces is:

```
    <p:barcode value="0123456" type="qr" height="95px"/>
```

I'am just getting image icon. Any solutions on this will be helpfull

Thank you

Comment: PF showcase works fine. Check your browser developer tool for network 404's on the image

Comment: but after adding qrgen-1.4 jar server is not starting. I'm using jBoss server error in server is as follows: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.zxing.Writer . Any Idea on this?? where i need too add this class?

Comment: Yes, it is a dependency. Look at the qrgen site for more info or just use maven or similar and all this will be resolved for you

Comment: Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22781101/exception-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-with-qrgen-and-zxing-libraries